# im creating a c++ program where the user has 2 attempts in trying a password username combo. If they cant get it they program stops

Tags: c++, while-loop, passwords

This is the error I am getting. I am just now moving on from python to c++ and it is a huge adjustment. This is the description of the program: Write your program so that it creates 3 or more valid username/password combinations, then prompts the user to enter a username and a password.  If the combination is valid, print a confirmatory message.  If the combination is invalid on the first try, print a warning message and let the user try one more time (prompt them again for a username and then a password).  If the second try is correct, print a confirmatory message.  If the second try is incorrect, print a chiding message.  In either case, halt the program after the second attempt.  Show the output for three cases:  correct username/password on first attempt; correct on second attempt; incorrect on both attempts.

```
$ g++ username_password.cpp -o username_password
username_password.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
username_password.cpp:34:2: error: ‘else’ without a previous ‘if’
  else if (username != "Veasy62" && username != "tveasy62" && username != "terriyon62" && password != "a65908" && password != "a1065908" && password != "Aa1065908");
  ^




#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()

{

    int pswrd_attempts = 0;
    string username;
    string password;
    cout << "Enter your username: " << "\n";
    getline( cin, username, '\n' );
    cout << "Enter your password: " << "\n";
    getline( cin, password, '\n' );
    while (username != "Veasy62" && username != "tveasy62" && username != "terriyon62" && password != "a65908" && password != "a1065908" && password != "Aa1065908");
    {
        pswrd_attempts++;
        cout << "Enter your username: " << "\n";
        getline( cin, username, '\n' );
        cout << "Enter your password: " << "\n";
        getline( cin, password, '\n' );

        if (pswrd_attempts > 2)

        {
            cout << "You've ran out of attempts" << "\n";
        }

    }
    else if (username == "Veasy62" && username == "tveasy62" && username == "terriyon62" && password == "a65908" && password == "a1065908" && password == "Aa1065908");
    {
        cout << "Correct password!" << "\n";



    }





}
```

Comment: I hope those aren't your real passwords...

Answer (score 1):

You have a semicolon at the end of the line where you define the `while` statement.  This will create all kinds of havoc.

The other problem, the one that you report, is because your `else` clause is outside of what is supposed to be the `while` scope, rather than being attached to the `if`.

Answer (score 0):

if you check your IF statement, the corresponding else it in the wrong block level:

```
    if (pswrd_attempts > 2)
        {
            cout << "You've ran out of attempts" << "\n";
        }
```

**}**

```
    else if...
```

You need to move that closing parenthesis behind the els if block.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are trying to achieve.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <conio.h>

void printAttempts( unsigned attempts, const std::string& messageTryAgain, const std::string messageOutOfAttempts ) {
    if ( attempts == 0 ) {
        std::cout << messageTryAgain << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << messageOutOfAttempts << std::endl;
    }
} // printAttempts

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> vUserNames;
    std::vector<std::string> vPasswords;

    vUserNames.push_back( "username1" );
    vUserNames.push_back( "username2" );
    vUserNames.push_back( "username3" );

    vPasswords.push_back( "pass1" );
    vPasswords.push_back( "pass2" );
    vPasswords.push_back( "pass3" );

    unsigned passwordAttempts = 0;
    std::string username;
    std::string password;

    const std::string tryAgain( "You have 1 attempt remaining.\n" );
    const std::string outOfAttempts( "You are out of attempts.\n" );

    while ( passwordAttempts < 2 ) {
        std::cout << "Enter your username: " << "\n";
        getline( std::cin, username, '\n' );

        std::cout << "Enter your password: " << "\n";
        getline( std::cin, password, '\n' );

        bool usernameFound = false;
        bool passwordFound = false;

        for ( unsigned u = 0; u < vUserNames.size(); ++u ) {
            if ( username == vUserNames.at( u ) ) {
                usernameFound = true;
                continue;
            }
        }

        for ( unsigned p = 0; p < vPasswords.size(); ++p ) {
            if ( password == vPasswords.at( p ) ) {
                passwordFound = true;
                continue;
            }
        }

        if ( usernameFound && passwordFound ) {
            std::cout << "You have successfully entered a valid username(" << username << ") and password(" << password << ")" << std::endl;
            break; // Uncomment this line to check out all possible combinations; The loop will continue until you run out of attempts.

        } else if ( usernameFound && !passwordFound ) {
            std::cout << "You have entered a valid user name(" << username << ")" << std::endl
                      << "however, you have entered an invalid password(" << password << ")" << std::endl;
            printAttempts( passwordAttempts, tryAgain, outOfAttempts );

        } else if ( !usernameFound && passwordFound ) {
            std::cout << "You have entered an invalid username(" << username << ")" << std::endl
                      << "You did however entered a valid password(" << password << ")" << std::endl;
            printAttempts( passwordAttempts, tryAgain, outOfAttempts );

        } else {
            std::cout << "You have entered an invalid username(" << username << ") and password(" << password << ")" << std::endl;
            printAttempts( passwordAttempts, tryAgain, outOfAttempts );
        }
        passwordAttempts++;
    }

    std::cout << "\nPress any key to quit" << std::endl;
    _getch();

} // main
```

Let me know how this works out for you.

Comment: As a challenge try to map each username to a specific password.